# Can't read second barcode in the same image file using pyzbar

Tags: python, python-2.7, barcode

I'm coding in Python 2.7 and I need to implement a process where I will read a PDF then obtain the image of the first page of the document, then from that image that contains two barcodes obtain the values of both. As of now these are the two functions I've been working on so far (I need to do a lot of polishing before I move this to an environment):

**Python process to obtain the image from the PDF from a Tutorial:**

```
from wand.image import Image as wi
pdf = wi(filename="test.pdf", resolution=300)
pdfImageTest = pdf.convert("png")
i=1
for img in pdfImage.sequence:
  page = wi
  (image = img)
  page.save(filename="test"+str(i)+".png")
  i+=1
```

**Python process to read the barcodes from an image:**

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy

decodedObjects = decode(Image.open('test2.png'))
obj = decodedObjects
print(obj)
decodedObjects = decode(cv2.imread('test2.png'))
print(obj)
```

According to the documentation for decode function in pyzbar, the function will scan all the barcodes contained in the image but as of now for both cases I've used, I'm only obtaining the first barcode in the image. Is there a way to force the function to keep scanning the image or pointing it into a specific location of the image after finishing the process for the first image?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `obj.data` and iterate over all objects.
Here's an example:

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy

decodedObjects = decode(Image.open('test2.png'))
obj = decodedObjects
for bar in obj:
  print(bar.data)
```

By the way, the `print` statement is replaced with `print()` function in Python 3. So if you strictly want to use Python 2.7, you should use e.g. `print bar.data`.

Comment: And, should rename `obj` to `foo`. For consistency.

Comment: Well I was referring to barcodes with `bar` but good point! :)

Comment: i have a same issue here, does anyone solved this problem?